# how to convert a list from polar cordinates to cartesian coordinates in python?

Tags: python

I have two list. One contains distance from the center and another contains the angle. Now how can i convert these two list into cartesian and put them in a single array?

for example:

```
distance = [10,12,10]
angle= [0,45,90]
```

How can i convert them into cartesian cordinate {x,y} cordinate. They should be in a list as [(x,y)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For conversion to cartesian coordinates, you need these equations:

```
x = r*cos(phi)
y = r*sin(phi)
```

With this, we can use a python list comprehension to calculate the new list:

```
import math 

cart = [(r*math.cos(phi*math.pi/180), r*math.sin(phi*math.pi/180)) for r, phi in zip(distance, angle)]
```

You need to convert the angles to radians with a factor `pi/180`.

The `zip` function essentially combines the two lists. For a real explanation, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy to compute the `sine` and `cosine` functions.

```
import numpy as np
import math

distance = [10,12,10]
angle= [0,45,90]

coord = []
for i,j in zip(distance,angle):
    coord.append((i*np.cos(math.pi*j/180), i*np.sin(math.pi*j/180)))
print(coord)
```

Comment: There is an error in this answer - you are passing degrees into `cos` and `sin` but those functions expect radians

Comment: There is still a factor of `pi` missing though